# In Fragment, GoogleMap, The setMyLocationEnabled (true) button is displayed only after I restart the application

Tags: android

After the first inclusion, the application requests permission to detect the location and the **setMyLocationEnabled (true)** button is not displayed on map.

The **setMyLocationEnabled (true)** button is displayed only after I restart the application or switch to another fragment, then return to the map again.

Could it be that I use fragments and because of this the application works this way?

please help solve this problem.

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private FusedLocationProviderClient _mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 101;

    private GoogleMap _map;
    private Location _mLastKnownLocation;

    SharedManager _manager;
    Connect _connect;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _manager = new SharedManager(getActivity());
        _connect = new Connect();
        _mFusedLocationProviderClient = 
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        getLocation();
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        _map = googleMap;

        _map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        _map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        _map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        _map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    private void getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 
    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            return;
        }

        Task<Location> locationResult = _mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();

        locationResult.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment)
                        getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_View);
                mapFrag.getMapAsync(MapFragment.this);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
    {
                    getLocation();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
 }



 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I will be glad to any advice.

Comment: did you add necessary permission to android manifest

Comment: yes of course added, edited the message